# Timer Task is executing so many times when date is changing in Grails

Tags: java, grails, grails-2.0, timertask

I am working with Grails 2.4.2. I am trying to print a text in each minute automatically. For that I googled some and try TimerTask with calendar instance. It is working fine when I run the app.

But if I change the date of my machine then It is printing so many times. But what I want is, it will print only single time in each minute although I change my machine date. What can I try next?

Here is my attempt below in my BootStrap.groovy file:

```
 class BootStrap {
    def init = { servletContext ->        
        int month=0,day=0,hour=0,minute=0,second=0
        def task = {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date toDay = new Date()
            calendar.setTime(toDay);
            month = calendar.get(calendar.MONTH)
            day = calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            println("Month is >> " + month)
            println("Day is >> " + day)
            println("Hour is >> " + hour)
            println("Minute is >> " + minute)
            println("second is >> " + second)
            println "executing task"
        } as TimerTask
        def oneMinuteInMs = 1000 * 60
        // Schedule the task
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, minute, oneMinuteInMs)
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you're passing the minute variable.

It should be enough to call for a recurring call every minute:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, oneMinuteInMs)
```

See:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)